# Awesome WM autostart programs in specific tabs

Tags: arch-linux, tabs, awesome-wm, autostart

I'm running **Awesome WM** v3.5.1 on ArchLinux and I would like to automatically open some programs at startup in specific tabs (like opening a terminal in the "main" tab, a browser in "web" or a text editor and a terminal in the "dev" tab).

I tried using rules in `rc.lua` but I want to put in specific tabs the programs only at startup and not the ones I manually start. Also they shouldn't mess up when I use the `restart` button of the window manager.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

add to rc.lua and try

i have multiple monitors, it is not being able to set it to the desired tag, maybe it can work on 1 monitor

```
function spawn_once(command, class, tag)
-- create move callback
local callback
callback = function(c)
if c.class == class then
awful.client.movetotag(tag, c)
client.remove_signal("manage", callback)
end
end
client.add_signal("manage", callback)
-- now check if not already running!
local findme = command
local firstspace = findme:find(" ")
if firstspace then
findme = findme:sub(0, firstspace-1)
end
-- finally run it
awful.util.spawn_with_shell("pgrep -u $USER -x " .. findme .. " > /dev/null || (" .. command .. ")")
end

-- use the spawn_once
spawn_once("subl", "Sublime_text", tags[1][2])
spawn_once("chromium", "Chromium", tags[1][3])
spawn_once("thunar", "Thunar", tags[1][4])
spawn_once("xchat", "Xchat", tags[1][5])
-- }}}
```